# Get active route hash in activate method

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

I have a two routes with different hashes and same view model:

```
var routes = [
    { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'Home', nav: 1 },
    { route: 'details(/:id)', moduleId: 'details', title: 'Details', nav: 2, hash: '#details'  },
    { route: 'access_token=*token', moduleId: 'details', title: 'Details', nav: false, hash: "#access_token=" }];
```

How I can detect the way I came to details view model in `activate` method of details view model? I tried to iterate over `router.routes` array and find route with isActive() == true, but this doesn't available till activate method returns result.

Also, if I add detecting of active route into `binding` method of view model, I getting both routes active, regardless of which route was applied:

```
function binding() {

    router.routes.forEach(function (route) {
        console.log('Route ' + route.hash + " isActive:" + route.isActive());
    });
}
```

Console log:

```
Route # isActive:false details.js:37
Route #details isActive:true details.js:37
Route #access_token= isActive:true
```

Comment: To clarify you are trying to find the previous route or the route that you are navigating to?  Have you looked at the activeInstruction?

Comment: @PWKad thanks a lot! That's exactly what I searching for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the router's activeInstruction property -

```
router.activeInstruction();
```

You can subscribe to it or create an computed off of it to track changes in the route.

Comment: more specifically, `router.activeInstruction().fragment` will get you the full durandal route.